# I have a closed question but it should be opened

Tags: support, reopen-closed

I have a question which is closed as a duplicate.  I have reworded the question because the "duplicate" doesn't answer my question.

I have now come up with my own solution but can't post my answer which actually works unlike the "duplicate" questions answer.

I have tried to flag it to re-open but that hasn't worked.  What can I do?

Comment: Your question is currently in the reopen queue, where other users will look if the question should be reopened or stay closed. If it gets reopened you can post your answer under your question. Right now you got 2 out of 5 reopen votes on your question.

Comment: BTW don't get scared from the votes here. [Voting is different on meta.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: What do you mean by "tried to flag it to re-open" though? It almost feels as if you were about to flag your post with a custom flag for a moderator to review. That isn't necessary... it's actually the wrong thing to do. Editing your question, then a bit of patience, is the right thing to do :)

Comment: I think I saw on another stack site that sometimes you had to post on the meta version to get attention to a closed question you wanted open.  Apparently that doesn't need to be done here.

Comment: @AdamHeeg nah here there is indeed no need for that. Editing your post is enough

Answer (score 6):

You need to be more patient, and leave a bit more time for people to reopen the question if they feel it merits reopening.  Questions don't get reopened in just a few seconds after you edit your question.